# Выполнение условия через секунду в юнити

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет! как сделать такую логику: если объект стоит на месте, то что - то происходит. у меня есть карта(это карточная игра) и если эта карта стоит1 секунду и не двигается, то создается объект(череp Instantiate()). Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Смотрите, у меня есть карта(это карточная игра) и если эта карта стоит1 секунду и не двигается, то создается объект(череp Instantiate())

Answer (score 0):

Изучай корутины. Вот пример:

```
        private bool _isCondition; // для условия
        private IEnumerator _waitCoroutine; // хранение корутины, необходим для ссылки на запущенную корутину

        private void Start()
        {
            _waitCoroutine = WaitForInstantiate(); // присваивание корутины
        }

        private void CheckCondition()
        {
            if (_isCondition) // если условие выполняется то запускаем корутину
            {
                StartCoroutine(_waitCoroutine);
            }
            else // если условие не выполнено, то останавливаем корутину если она запустилась
            {
                StopCoroutine(_waitCoroutine);
                
                // StopAllCoroutines(); // Есть возможность остановить все корутины в данном скрипте
            }
        }

        private IEnumerator WaitForInstantiate()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f); // Ожидание 1 сек.

            Instantiate(new GameObject()); // Необходимое действие
        }
```

Comment: я про корутины знаю и ими часто пользуюсь. но сейчас я попробовал и не получил требуемого результата

Comment: IEnumerator CheckForStay()
    {
        if (rb.velocity == Vector3.zero)
        {
            Spawn.position = butt.position;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
            if (rb.velocity == Vector3.zero)
            {
                Spawn.position = butt.position;
                Instantiate(FirstCircle, Spawn.position, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    } так не работает нормально

Comment: `не получил требуемого результата`, `не работает нормально` -- в ответ на это хочется только пожелать, чтобы все заработало нормально и закрыть вкладку StackOverflow. Мало того, что вы указываете код в комментарии (что выглядит ужасно), так еще и не в вопросе, а под чужим ответом, а не В ТЕКСТЕ ВОПРОСА, так еще и не говорите в чем конкретно проблема, что конкретно не работает! `Ну НиНаЮ Не РаБоТаЕт А шО ПоДеЛаТь`.

Comment: Знать это не изучать! Если не добились требуемого результата значит условие для проверки поставлено не правильно, в любом случае никто не сможет помочь Вам полностью подробным решением, я попытался навести вас на путь, попробуйте вести проверку на условие в `Update()` если условие нарушается останавливайте корутину

Answer (score -1):

Для этого нужно использовать класс Time. Ниже приведен пример кода.

```
    public float second;
    public bool isImmovable = false;
    private Vector3 objectPosition;

    void Start()
    {
        objectPosition = transform.position;
        oneSecond = 1;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        oneSecond -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (oneSecond <= 0)
        {
            oneSecond = 1;
            if (objectPosition == transform.position)
                isImmovable = true;
            else if (objectPosition != transform.position)
            {
                objectPosition = transform.position;
                isImmovable = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это делается корутиной а не в Update.